# What does 'to get nowhere fast' mean and why 'Unfortunately'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does 'to get nowhere fast' mean and why 'Unfortunately'?

> A quick course in how **to get nowhere fast** on social media.
>   **Unfortunately**, I've seen them all:

source:
https://www.artbusiness.com/artists-how-to-hex-your-online-profile.html

Comment: "To get nowhere fast" is an idiom that means to expend a lot of energy without achieving anything worthwhile.

Comment: To get nowhere is to fail to achieve anything or to make progress; adding "fast" intensifies the degree of failure.

Answer (score 1):

"**To get nowhere fast**" is an [idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+nowhere+fast) meaning "**to be unsuccessful or to fail to make progress**."

The author writes "unfortunately" before a list of unsuccessful social media strategies to say that **it is unfortunate that these are so common**.

Answer (score 0):

**To get nowhere** means to not succeed, to fail in one's attempts.

> We got nowhere trying to convince them to delay the production release.

To get nowhere *fast* means to fail quickly.  You don't have to wait long to find out that your efforts have been fruitless.  It's often a way of giving advice to someone; it's as if to say "That path leads *directly* to failure" or "That path will *soon* lead to failure".

> You can advertise on Google all you want, but if your website is shite, you'll get nowhere fast.

Comment: If we are "going nowhere fast" that can mean the situation is deteriorating rapidly.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Yes, but    **get** and **going** mean different things. And now it's dinnertime and I need to get going.